# XML image Loading issue in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

In my application news displaying through  XML parser  , The problem is In my XMl url few images are named with Arabic language those images are loading , If its named with English (Ex.dsc_5804.jpg) its displaying fine and if its named with Arabic (Ex.لجنة%20تطوير%20الإعلام%20في%20الشورى%20تبدأ%20ف.jpg) its not displaying , i am not sure the issue with image format or from my code or something else  can any tel me the solution for this please ??

YOU CAN SEE MY SCREEN SHOT ALSO [CLICK](http://www.innovativeoranges.com/imageissue.jpg)  HERE

Image url link [here](http://www.shura.bh/mediacenter/news/councilstatment/publishingimages/%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%20%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AB%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%86%2011%D9%80%20%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%20%D9%80%202013%D9%85%20%287%29.jpg)

**Here is my NewsViewController.m**

```
#import "NewsViewController.h"
#import "NewsTableViewCell.h"
#import "NewDetailsViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import "SearchVC.h"
@interface NewsViewController ()
{
    NSString *temString;
    NSMutableString *strTemp;
    BOOL isDateSearch;
}

@end

@implementation NewsViewController
@synthesize arrImages;
@synthesize TittleOne;
@synthesize TittleTwo;
@synthesize TittleThree;
@synthesize datepicker;
@synthesize PickerContainer;
@synthesize datepickerTittle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View Life Cycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinnerView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [TittleOne setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12]];
    [TittleTwo setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:10]];
    [TittleThree setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:10]];
    // [[UIColor redColor] set];
    [datepickerTittle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12]];
    // [datepickerTittle.textColor= [UIColor yellowColor]];

    isDateSearch=NO;
    self.arrTitles =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.arrDescription=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrDate=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrUrls=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrDateSearch=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(requestingForNews:) withObject:nil];

    // dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), s^{
    self.spinnerView.hidden=YES;
    [self makeRequestForNews];
    //  self.spinnerView.stopAnimating;
    //});

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self imagedownloader:@"http://www.shura.bh/MediaCenter/News/"];
}
-(void)requestingForNews:(id)sender
{
    [self makeRequestForNews];
}
-(void) imagedownloader : (NSString *)urlStringOfImage
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        //downlaod image
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringOfImage];
        NSData  *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50 )];
            imageView.image = image;
            [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        });
    });
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma  mark - make request for news
-(void)makeRequestForNews
{

    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:self.strNewsApi];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //After making request the apparent thing is expecting the response that may be expected response or an Error. so create those objects and intialize them with NULL.
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError =NULL;
    //Once you have response with you , Capture YOur Responce data using NsData.

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    //Convert the respnse Data into Response String.

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Now We can start parsing the Data using XMl parser . you need XML parser in-order to use the below class method "dictionaryFOrXMLString".

    NSError *parserError = NULL;

    //XML parsing

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];

    //    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    //    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    //NSDictionary *xmlDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseString error:NULL];

    //once you have xmlDict handy, you can pass this to the any ViewController (Like table view) to populate the Data.
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{


    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {

    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {

    }
    strTemp=[NSMutableString new];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //temString =string;
    [strTemp appendString:string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"TITLE"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrTitles addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGECONTENT"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrDescription addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"NEWSARTICLEDATE"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrDate addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {

        NSLog(@"tempImage=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrImages addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {
        [self.tblNews reloadData];
        // self.spinnerView.hidden=YES;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"URL"])
    {
        [self.arrUrls addObject:strTemp];
    }

}

#pragma mark - TabeView Datasource//delegate method

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isDateSearch)
    {
        return [self.arrDateSearch count];
    }
    else{
        return [self.arrTitles count];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellNews";
    NewsTableViewCell *cell=(NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NewsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        // cell.NewsTableViewCell.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x000000);
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


    }

    if( [indexPath row] % 2){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =UIColorFromRGB(0Xffffff);

    }
    else{
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =UIColorFromRGB (0Xdcdcdc);
    }

    //selectbackground color start
    UIView *NewsTableViewCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    NewsTableViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0Xdcdcdc);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = NewsTableViewCell; //select background colro end
    cell.lblTitles.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12];
    if (isDateSearch)
    {
        cell.lblTitles.text=[[self.arrDateSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
    }
    else{
        cell.lblTitles.text=[self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.lblDescription.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"GE SS Unique" size:12];
    cell.lblDate.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GE SS Unique" size:12];
    if (isDateSearch)
    {
        cell.lblDescription.text=[[self.arrDateSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"des"];
    }
    else{
        cell.lblDescription.text=[self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.lblDate.text=[self.arrDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblTitles.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.lblDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.lblDescription.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    //SDWebImage Code for lazy loader
    [cell.imgNews setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]

                        completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

                         //   if (![self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
                            if ((cell.imgNews.image = image))
                            {
                                cell.imgNews.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
                                cell.imgNews.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;

                            }
                            else {

                             //  if (!cell.imgNews ==nil)
                            if (!cell.imgNews.image)
                                {

                                    cell.lblTitles.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblTitles.frame.origin.x, cell.lblTitles.frame.origin.y, 283, cell.lblTitles.frame.size.height);
                                    cell.lblDate.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblDate.frame.origin.x, cell.lblDate.frame.origin.y, 286, cell.lblDate.frame.size.height);
                                    cell.lblDescription.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.x, cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.y, 281, cell.lblDescription.frame.size.height);
                                    cell.imgNews.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
                                    cell.imgNews.layer.borderWidth = 0;


                                }
                            }

                        }];

    // cell.imgNews.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
//    cell.imgNews.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
//    cell.imgNews.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    [PickerContainer setHidden:YES];
//    if (!cell.imgNews.image)
//    {
//        cell.lblTitles.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblTitles.frame.origin.x, cell.lblTitles.frame.origin.y, 283, cell.lblTitles.frame.size.height);
//        cell.lblDate.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblDate.frame.origin.x, cell.lblDate.frame.origin.y, 286, cell.lblDate.frame.size.height);
//        cell.lblDescription.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.x, cell.lblDescription.frame.origin.y, 281, cell.lblDescription.frame.size.height);
//        cell.imgNews.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
//        cell.imgNews.layer.borderWidth = 0;
//    }
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict=nil;
    if (isDateSearch)
    {
        //dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrDateSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"]],@"title",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrDateSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"des"]],@"img",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"Des",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"url", nil];
    }
    else{
        dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                                          [self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"title",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                                                                                                  [self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"img",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                                                                                                                                                        [self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"Des",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"url", nil];
    }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewsDetailsID" sender:dict];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NewsDetailsID"])
    {
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strTitle=[sender objectForKey:@"title"];
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strDetailImage=[sender objectForKey:@"img"];
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strDescription=[sender objectForKey:@"Des"];//strUrl
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strUrl=[sender objectForKey:@"url"];
    }
}

- (IBAction)backBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)DatePickerBt:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    PickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 261);
    [PickerContainer setHidden:NO];
}
- (IBAction)HideButton:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    PickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0,600, 320, 261);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if ([self.arrDateSearch count])
    {
        [self.arrDateSearch removeAllObjects];
    }
    if ([self.arrDate count])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<[self.arrDate count]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"arrdate === %@",self.arrDate);

            NSArray *arrDateStr=[[self.arrDate objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
            NSArray *arrDat=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDateStr objectAtIndex:0]] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

            NSString *strDat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",[arrDat objectAtIndex:2],[arrDat objectAtIndex:1],[arrDat objectAtIndex:0]];
            NSString *strPicDat=[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.datepicker.date]componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@" strpic date === %@",strPicDat);
            if ([strDat isEqualToString:strPicDat])
            {
                isDateSearch=YES;
                NSDictionary *dictTemp=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:i],@"title",[self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:i],@"des",[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:i],@"img", nil];
                [self.arrDateSearch addObject:dictTemp];
                NSLog(@"dates equal");
            }

        }

        [self.tblNews reloadData];

    }
}
- (IBAction)ReloadButton:(id)sender {
    self.spinnerView.hidden=NO;
    isDateSearch=NO;
    [self makeRequestForNews];
    NSLog(@"RELOADING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

}
@end
```

Comment: Its probably got something to do with the percentage escapes "%20". Not sure though

Comment: can you give me any example please ...?

Comment: @user3744932 Can you just try one thing copy the url from your log and paste in browser, do browser show the image ?

Comment: yes in the browser it shows image .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code

```
-(void) imagedownloader : (NSString *)urlStringOfImage
{
    urlStringOfImage = [urlStringOfImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//OR

    urlStringOfImage = [urlStringOfImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 // DO YOUR NORMAL STUFF YOU WERE DOING.

}
```

**Update**

I think in your case the other method that is `stringByReplacingPercent` rather than `stringByAddingPercent` should work, try following

```
urlStringOfImage = [urlStringOfImage stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Update2**

The url you gave is not a valid url `see image`, I think you should report to the webservice developer to put valid url encoding, or better change your webservice for image urls, with use of `uniqueID` or, something.

[image]

Comment: hi , I tried with this urlStringOfImage = [urlStringOfImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] the image cell is hiding but image is not loading , i want load all the images ??

Comment: Try other encoding options like `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` see which one works..

Comment: NSASCIIStringEncoding, NSISOLatin1StringEncoding , these two also same condition its not loading ?

Comment: [cell.imgNews setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]].as you said i added like this but still not coming . ??

Comment: @user3744932 yes correct, can you please provide on of the image url so that I can check ?

Comment: Hi the Image url is :http://www.shura.bh/mediacenter/news/chairmandeputies/publishingimages/الصورة%20الرسمية%20لمعالي%20رئيس%20مجلس%20الشورى.jpg

Comment: @user3744932 See my `Update2`

Comment: See one more URl also : http://www.shura.bh/mediacenter/news/councilstatment/publishingimages/صور%20جلسة%20الأثنين%2011ـ%20مارس%20ـ%202013م%20(7).jpg

Comment: I tried your  above code  too its not working .When i copy paste  the url from the comment box its happened to me same (Bad Request). Because  its arabic language so that words might be changed while you copying from the comment box . .But when i copy the URL from My debugger Area the image is coming . you can have a look at my screen shot :http://www.innovativeoranges.com/Screen%20Shot%202014-06-24%20at%209.42.12.png .What i feel the problem from the " 20% " because of this spacing its not loading i guess ?? i do not know how solve this issue ??

Comment: IN my question i have give the image url link please click that one you can see the image .